# How do I use Synchronization in POSIX semaphores?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, semaphore

I have gotten to chapter 6 (Deadlocks) in *Operating System Concepts* by Silbersechatz, Galvin and Gagne. I'm trying to make a program that creates vehicles as separate threads heading north or south across a one way bridge. If there's a vehicle on the bridge, that vehicle/thread will sleep (like traveling across the bridge). I'm struggling a bit with when the car is good to go (or cross the bridge).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define MAX_WAIT 3 // how many seconds each car will wait at most

typedef struct _VEHICLE {
    pthread_t t;
    int isNorth;
    int idx;
    int waitfor;
} VEHICLE;

sem_t sem; // bridge
sem_t goodToCross = 1;

void enter_bridge(char* direction, int idx) {
    printf("1 - %s vehicle %d is about to enter the bridge\n", direction, idx);
    goodToCross.wait(&sem);
    printf("2 - %s vehicle %d has entered the bridge\n", direction, idx);
}

void exit_bridge(char* direction, int idx) {
  printf("5 - %s vehicle %d has left the bridge\n", direction, idx);

    goodToCross.signal(&sem);
}

void* pass_bridge(void* param) {
    VEHICLE* f = (VEHICLE*) param;
    char* direction = f->isNorth ? "North" : "South";

    enter_bridge(direction, f->idx);
    printf("3 - %s vehicle %d will pass the bridge in %d seconds\n", direction, f->idx, f->waitfor);
    sleep(f->waitfor);
    printf("4 - %s vehicle %d has passed the bridge in %d seconds\n", direction, f->idx);

    exit_bridge(direction, f->idx);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    VEHICLE* v_north;
    VEHICLE* v_south;

    int nNorthVehicles, nSouthVehicles;

    if (argc != 3) {
      printf("Usage: ./main (Num North Vehicles) (Num South Vehicles)\n");
      return 1;
    }

    nNorthVehicles = atoi(argv[1]);
    nSouthVehicles = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (nNorthVehicles <= 0 || nSouthVehicles <= 0) {
      printf("Error number of vehicles given is not a valid number\n");
      return 1;
    }

    v_north = (VEHICLE*)malloc(sizeof(VEHICLE) * nNorthVehicles);
    v_south = (VEHICLE*)malloc(sizeof(VEHICLE) * nSouthVehicles);

    printf("we have %d vehicles from the north and %d vehicles the south\n", nNorthVehicles, nSouthVehicles);

    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);

    for (i = 0; i < nNorthVehicles; ++i) {
      v_north[i].isNorth = 1;
      v_north[i].idx = 1;
      v_north[i].waitfor = rand() % MAX_WAIT;
      pthread_create(&(v_north[i].t), 0, pass_bridge, &(v_north[i]));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nSouthVehicles; ++i) {
      v_south[i].isNorth = 0;
      v_south[i].idx = 1;
      v_south[i].waitfor = rand() % MAX_WAIT;
      pthread_create(&(v_south[i].t), 0, pass_bridge, &(v_south[i]));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nNorthVehicles; ++i) {
      pthread_join(v_north[i].t, NULL);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nSouthVehicles; i++) {
      pthread_join(v_south[i].t, NULL);
    }

    sem_destroy(&sem);

    printf("All vehicles have passed\n");

    free(v_north);
    free(v_south);

    return 0;
}
```

My issues are definitely in/with the `goodToCross` semaphore - I can't figure out how to correctly define it.

Comment: `goodToCross.signal(&sem)` -- This code does not appear to be C.  Please tag the language you are actually using, or else use the language you have actually tagged.

Comment: With that said, the basic idea appears sound.  A thread must decrement the semaphore to get onto the bridge, and such a thread then increments it again when it clears the bridge.  What, then, is the nature of the problem?  Are you just uncertain about how to call semaphore functions and / or which ones to call?

Comment: You only need a single semaphore for this example. It protects the bridge and its starting count represents how many vehicles may be on the bridge at any one time (just 1 in this case).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry - new to C, sort of learning it alongside Operating Systems here as I go through the book. I guess, considering that's not even c I'm unsure of how to properly implement my entering/exiting of the bridge. I guess that's the issue I'm having. I see bnaecker's comment that I only actually need 1 semaphore. So if I get rid of the GoodToCross I'm sort of just lost... :o

Comment: Semaphores are designed to protect a shared resource, limiting how "much" of it can be used at a time. In this case, the shared resource is the bridge, and one car can be on it at a time. See @bhow's answer, which helps explain this. You could also use a mutex, rather than a semaphore, if that helps explain the usage.

Comment: Be careful that you check sem_wait()'s return value of EINTR. If that happens you need to go back to waiting....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, can't add comments at my reputation.

Like what @bnaecker has said, you only need one semaphore. This is to keep track of whether or not the bridge is at max occupancy. Assuming only one car can be on the bridge at a time, when a car waits on the bridge semaphore for the first time, it will decrement the counter and proceed across the bridge. After that, while the car is still on the bridge, any other car trying to cross will also call wait. This time, each car will hang (or busy wait) until the bridge semaphore is incremented again (when the car currently on the bridge exits).

At that time, another car will get out of waiting and decrement the counter.

Edit: I'm unsure of the implementation of semaphore in c, so I'll just leave this at a high level description of the process.

Comment: So to follow up, in the `enter_bridge` we can just call `sem.wait()` instead of my `GoodToCross` and how do I go about signaling that the vehicle has left in the exit_bridge?

Comment: @NikkiNelson That's correct, except that as pointed out in one of the comments on your question, `sem.wait()` is not valid C code. Call `sem_wait()` inside `enter_bridge()` and `sem_post()` inside `exit_bridge()`.

Comment: ... and, of course, pass the appropriate arguments to the semaphore functions.  I point this out lest the OP be confused about the "sem" that is a prefix of the names of POSIX semaphore functions, relative to the distinct "sem" that is the name of a variable in his program.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry, are you saying I'm passing the wrong arguments?

Comment: No, @NikkiNelson.  I am speaking specifically to bnaecker's correction of "sem.wait()` to `sem_wait()`.  In particular, I'm pointing out that if the former is interpreted as pseudocode for calling a function to decrement the semaphore, of type `sem_t`, identified by "sem", then the latter is imperfectly analogous.  A closer analogue would be `sem_wait(&sem)`.

Comment: I was able to correct the enter and exit with the correct c syntax: `sem_wait(&sem)` and `sem_post(&sem)` -- my output (http://prntscr.com/gw9xgs) isn't as I expected so I guess I have other issues to look into